Collision Detection Between a Keyboard animated sprite and a timed one doesn't work
The player and the enemy don't collide.
They are layered together on different panels
    layeredPane.add(c, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    layeredPane.add(s, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);

In the circle file, I have this:
public boolean collidesWith(Sprite sprite) {
    if(sprite.getX() > x && sprite.getX() < (x + 50))
    {
        if(sprite.getY() > y && sprite.getY() < (y + 50))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

Where supposedly it is checked every time a key is pressed:
for(Sprite s: sprites) {
        System.out.println("Checking collision: Circle at (" + x + ", " + y + "), Sprite at (" + 
s.getX() + ", " + s.getY() + ")");
        if(collidesWith(s)) {
            System.out.println("Collision detected!");
            setXY(20, 120);
        }
    }

I tried to put both the Player sprite and the enemy on the same file, but that doesn't work.
This didn't work either:
public boolean checkCollision(Sprite sprite) {
    Rectangle circleBounds = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50);
    Rectangle spriteBounds = new Rectangle(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), sprite.getWidth(), 
sprite.getHeight());
    return circleBounds.intersects(spriteBounds);
    }
}

